# XCode not responding to clicks on toolbar (for example to open Assistant Editor)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toolbar

**Clarification:** i mean the XCode Application Toolbar (the buttons on the top right: [image]).

first, im not asking for someone to **Solve** the issue as im sure its either a problem in my code that gives XCode problems OR its a bug in Xcode (and i dont expect anyone other than apple to fix it).

What i need to know is:

- did anyone else encounter this problem while working with XCode 7.3?
- does anyone know if this is an XCode bug? maybe i did something wrong in the code/storyboard to create a problem?
- if it is a bug: is there a known workaround?

Thanks for anyone who helps. Couldn't find any answer for this anywhere else.
Also, if i asked this the wrong way or did something wrong - please let me know in comments and ill update the post accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Funny that only after posting a question in StackOverflow - i solve it and its really dumb.

Apparently, i had a Storyboard inconsistency (probably because of a certain SCM Merge) with a certain Stack. deleting the stack and re-creating it solved the inconsistency and also solved the toolbar issue (and i really dont understand why they have anything to do with each other).

anyway: crisis averted :)